# ProcessStartInfo WorkigDirectory parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

i have a web application in which i want to execute an .exe file.

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
 info.WorkingDirectory = this.WorkingDirectory;
```

when i put my

```
info.WorkingDirecoty = Request.MapPath("~");
info.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/theFile.exe");
```

it works. But when I put them like this:

```
info.WorkingDirecoty = "~";
info.FileName = "~/theFile.exe";
```

it doesnt work, why ?? and how can i solve this problem ?? or should i always use the Server.MapPath???

Comment: Where is the difference between your last two code snippets?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Server.MapPath?

Comment: @PVitt : typing mistake. I edited them

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: i want to use them in my class when the ServerMapth doesnt work

Comment: @Grace see edited post, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MSDN says

> Server.MapPath Method
>
> The MapPath method maps the specified
>   relative or virtual path to the
>   corresponding physical directory on
>   the server.

and you need to give direct file path to ProcessStartInfo
So you should use Server.MapPath in this case

If you don't want to use Server.MapPath because of reference to System.Web you can create a BaseDir property in that library class, and pass it from out world where you have reference to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yep thats what i was doing ..but i thought there is a way not to use the Server.MapPath, thanks again.